# How to get the information of Logged in user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently building a web application where i need to get the information regarding the user who logged in and I want to get that emailID through which he/she logged in.
So how can I access the user email property so as to use that emailID.

In the "/orders" route where I want to display all orders of that logged in person, and I want to access the property of email through which the person is logged in, so that i can use that email and lookup into my database whether or not he has placed some order. So how can I get that email property ?

Here's my JS Code

```py
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const User = require("./models/User");
const Order = require("./models/Order");


mongoose.connect(process.env.DbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("connected to db!");
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("error", err);
    });

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "views");

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(session({ secret: "keepABetterSecretThanThis", resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));

const isLogin = (req,res,next) => {
    if(!req.session.userId)
        res.redirect("/login");
    else
        next();
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.render("signup");
});

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.firstName;
    const lastName = req.body.lastName;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const user = new User({firstName, lastName, email, password});
    await user.save();
    req.session.userId = user._id;
    res.redirect("/login");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("signup");
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const foundUser = await User.findAndValidate(email, password);
   
    if (foundUser) {
        req.session.userId = foundUser._id;
      if (email === "B119016@iiit-bh.ac.in" && password === "sagar2019.")
        res.render("admin");
      else res.redirect("/orders");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
});

app.get("/orders", (req, res, next) => {
    const emailaddress = req.session.userId;
    console.log(email);
    const individualOrder = Order.find({ emailID: emailaddress });

    individualOrder.exec(function (err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render("orders", { records: data });

    });

});

app.get("/placeOrder", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.userId) {
        res.render("placeOrder");
    }
});

app.post("/placeOrder", async (req, res) => {
    const Date = req.body.bf_totalGuests;
    const PickupState = req.body.pickupstate;
    const PickupCity = req.body.pickupcity;
    const DropState = req.body.dropstate;
    const DropCity = req.body.dropcity;
    const firstandlastname = req.body.bf_name;
    const emailID = req.body.bf_email;
    const extraMessages = req.body.bf_extraMessages;

    try {
        const order = new Order({
          Date,
          PickupState,
          PickupCity,
          DropState,
          DropCity,
          firstandlastname,
          emailID,
          extraMessages,
        });
        await order.save();
        res.render("hello");
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    
});

app.post("/logout",(req,res)=>{
    req.session.userId = null;
    res.redirect("/login")
})
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening at " + ${port});
});
```

Comment: Did you disclose your real password in the code?

Comment: yeah, now its updated. I forgot to hide it.

Comment: You should not edit the post in such scenarios, rather delete the post and repost with proper details, as you see it does not delete from delete history.

Comment: coming to your issue, You can simply use that userId and fetch the email from the Db using that userId(I assume the userId and email are linked together in some users collection) and do your task.